# C# TcpClient get muiltiple packages in one miliseconds

Tags: c#

I am having a client and a server based on tcp messaging. Now all works well while I am sending one message at a time (one message is about 1400 byte frame) and from client side sending message is simple:

```
    private async Task SendFrame(TcpClient tcpClient, BaseTcpFrame message)
    {
        byte[] messageFrame = message.BuildFrame();
        await tcpClient.GetStream().WriteAsync(messageFrame, 0, messageFrame.Length);
    }
```

And from server side simple as well:

```
    private async Task StartReading(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        while (tcpClient != null && tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            var input = new byte[1400];
            await tcpClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(input, 0, input.Length);

            if (input.All(b => b == 0)) break;

            pingCount++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Ping {pingCount}");
        }
    }
```

And it works if you send one frame, in some logic time interval (ex 1 second).
But now I came across a problem if I implement something like send many frames asap on client side:

```
    protected override async Task HandleIncomingRequest(TcpClient tcpClient, List<ServiceResponse> multiResponse)
    {
        foreach (ServiceResponse responseChunk in multiResponse.ChunkedResponse)
        {
            await SendMessage(tcpClient, responseChunk);
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending response part - {responseChunk.ResultFrameNumber} od {responseChunk.ResultFramesCount}");
            // Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(TcpClient tcpClient, BaseTcpFrame message)
    {
        if (tcpClient != null && tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            await SendFrame(tcpClient, message);
        }
    }
```

Without thread sleep I see all messages are sent, but on server side I am getting one message, occasional two or three, but I add sleep i receive all.

So is there something I can do to avoid using thread sleep and receive all messages asap??

Comment: TCP doesn't do messaging. It does an endless stream of bytes. It looks like you may be part way their by talking about framing but the fact that you *ignore* the return value from `ReadAsync` means that you're not doing enough here.

Comment: That is, you almost certainly *are* receiving all "messages", they've probably *all* been placed in `input` in that *first* call to `ReadAsync`.